# In a 4/4 instrumental, do I have to write stressed syllables to land on the beats of the bar so that my lyrics can be "in time"?

Tags: theory

In a 4/4 instrumental, do I have to write stressed syllables to land on the beats of the bar so that my lyrics can be "in time"? If not, how can I make my lyrics be "in time"? Please write as much of a technical answer as possible.

Comment: This is an unusual use of the phrase "in time". Could you add more description of what you're asking?

Comment: I mean that for example if I'm singing to a backtrack, other than singing on key, what do i need to do to reach a sense of belonging with the instrumental.

Comment: Instrumentals don't have words. Do you mean using a backing track to sing along to?

Comment: Yes, I do mean a backing track.

Answer (score 2):

You don't **have** to. You should **want** to be aware of when the stressed syllables of the lyrics are lining up with the stressed beats and when they aren't.

When they don't line up, it can make the lyrics harder to understand and it can make the whole song sound awkward and amateurish. At the same time, when they don't line up, they can also make the moment stand out.

The overall topic of where the lyrics fall in the music and where the line breaks and stanzas are is called *prosody* and it's a very important aspect of songwriting.

If you're just learning to write songs, it's probably best to write so the stressed syllables in the lyrics line up with the stressed beats. If you write many songs like this to the point where it becomes part of your natural, instinctive process, then you'll have mastered an important skill of songwriting, and you'll find that working on prosody improves other aspects of your songwriting.